# Android: LiveData observeForEver produce crash because the views are null

Tags: android, android-livedata, lifecycle

For the purposes of my application I have live data that `observesForEver` and updates views. When I exit the application to background and return to foreground the application crashes in the views that is in the observers.

Here is the crash:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.emoona.music, PID: 7897
> java.lang.NullPointerException: this.titleTxt must not be null
> at com.emoona.torahboxmusic.features.playmusic.playlist.SelectPlaylistFragment.updateUI(SelectPlaylistFragment.kt:157)
> ................

My code:

```
viewModel.globalController.music.observeForever { music ->
            val music = music ?: return@observeForever
            this.titleTxt.text = music.title
        }
```

I declare the observer on `onViewCreated`

What should I do to avoid this crash? Why are views null in the observer?

I specify I don't want to do an `observe(viewLifeCycle)` because I need it to `observeForEver`

Comment: Your crash is **because** you're using `observeForever`. What makes you think you need to use `observeForever`?

Comment: In certain cases, I have an activity open on the fragment, and this activity must notify the observer of a new value.  If I set it in simple `observe`, the observer will not be notified from the activity on it.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. What do you mean activity open on the fragment? You mean vice versa? What is your logic: like activity,that has a fragment and this activity notify observer on fragmetn that something is new? We need more info to help you (that is more code)

Comment: no I mean I have an activity that contains a fragment, and from this fragment I open a new activity and this new activity must notify the observer of the fragment behind.  The fragment and the activity have a common manager which contains the field livedata which allows one (fragment) to observe and the other to notify (activity)

Comment: this.titleTxt make sure your titleTxt is initialized properly before setting text

Comment: this is a view of the XML via kotlin synthetic, so it should not be null

Comment: Your logic is invalid. Always assume activity in background might be destroyed (due to memory constraints) and doesn't exist.